# Bootstrap tooltips in Drupal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

Drupal 7, Bootstrap theme.
Tooltips are not working.

- Tooltips and smart form descriptions enabled in theme settings
- HTML seems ok
- Tooltips should be activated with extra JS

**HTML**

```
<input tabindex="2" class="form-control form-text" title="Enter something or leave blank 
for random" data-toggle="tooltip" type="text" id="edit-short-url" name="short_url" value="" 
size="6" maxlength="128" />
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
    });
</script>
```

**[See the page here](http://ovaj.link/)**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included `jquery version - v1.4.4` which is **obsolete** in a way which **twitter bootstrap** does not use/support. Also if you would have noted your browser console, you would have caught below errors, which are crystal clear explaining the problem.

> - ***`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher`***

followed by

> - ***`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`***

and

> - ***`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`***

Download the latest version of `jquery.js`, current latest is `v2.2.1` as of *`02/24/2016`* and refer it instead of `v1.4.4` which will fix the above issues.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)